# Python setuptools unable to find sub module of library

Tags: python, wxpython, setuptools

My first attempt at using python setuptools. I am using wxPython in the project. I am using the following import lines

```
import wx, random
from wx.lib import buttons
```

And in my `setup.py` I have

```
 setup(
      name='name',
      version='0.2p',
      description='...',
      author='...',
      author_email='...',
      packages=['name'],
        long_description=open(
          path.join(
              path.dirname(__file__),
              'README'
          )
      ).read(),
        install_requires=[
          'setuptools',
          'MySQL-python',
          'wx',
          'ObjectListView'
        ],)
```

When I use `easy_install` on the .egg everything seems fine. But when I run the main method from where the project has been installed, I get the failed import message:

```
from wx.lib import buttons
ImportError: No module named lib
```

Do I need to explicity require the `wx.lib` module in the setup.py file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your `setup.py` file, rather you're missing a step in your import statements. You need to explicitly import the `lib` module from `wx`. It should look something like this:

```
import wx
import wx.lib
from wx.lib import buttons
```

**Edit**: Actually, there is a problem with the `setup.py` `install_requires`. You want to require `wxPython` and **NOT** `wx`. `wx` is an entirely different package in Python's package index.

You do still need that extra `import wx.lib` in your import statements however.

Comment: Still getting an error:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/resnate-0.2p-py2.7.egg/resnate/WXView.py", line 8, in <module>
    import wx.lib
ImportError: No module named lib

Comment: Assuming you have updated your imports in the `resnate` package, did you reinstall?

Comment: Yes because it shows the "import wx.lib" line as the same problem

Comment: Apologies Sash, there is a problem with your setup.py. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: I have already tried it with "wxPython", with the exact same results

Comment: Make sure you uninstall `wx`. It is likely that you are experiencing a conflict between the two packages, as their actual module names are both `wx`.